# Vaadin with Spring (no Boot) and sub-context - "lookup is null"

Tags: java, spring, vaadin14

I'm trying to achieve the following architecture:

- One spring root context (containing business logic)
- One vaadin context
- One REST API context
  But the error is reproducible in a single project, as follows:

main package

```java
// Entry Point

public final class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setAddDefaultWebXmlToWebapp(false);
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
    tomcat.getConnector();

    Host host = tomcat.getHost();
    host.setAppBase(".");

    Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("", ".");

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
  }
}

// Main Initializer
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
  }
}

// Configuration - Would import DatabaseConfig etc.
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Vaadin package

```java
// Initializer

public class VaadinInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    // This is more or less copied from VaadinMVCWebAppInitializer
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext vaadinContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    vaadinContext.register(VaadinConfig.class);

    SpringServlet vaadinSpringServlet = new SpringServlet(vaadinContext, false);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic vaadinServletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet(
        ClassUtils.getShortNameAsProperty(SpringServlet.class), vaadinSpringServlet);

    vaadinServletRegistration.addMapping("/app/*");
    vaadinServletRegistration.setAsyncSupported(true);
  }
}

// Config

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import({VaadinScopesConfig.class, VaadinApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class VaadinConfig {
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [springServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileFromClassloader(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:341)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileContents(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:311)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.readBuildInfo(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:181)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createInitParameters(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:174)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createDeploymentConfiguration(VaadinServlet.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:190)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:77
```

The Vaadin `lookup` is `null` although it should be set through `VaadinApplicationConfiguration`. I guess that I'm doing something wrong in the way I set up the context hierachy / loading.

Versions: Spring 5.3.7, Vaadin 14.6.1, Vaadin-Spring: 12.4.0 (the error is slightly different for 14.5.5 but the root cause likely is the same)

For completeness: Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.6.0'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: "5.3.7"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: "5.3.7"

    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: "3.1.0"

    implementation group: 'com.vaadin', name: 'vaadin-core', version: "14.6.1"
    implementation group: 'com.vaadin', name: 'vaadin-spring', version: "12.4.0"

    implementation group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: "9.0.46"
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-el-api', version: "9.0.46"
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-jasper-el', version: "9.0.46"
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-websocket', version: "9.0.46"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately :(